# How to aggregate dimension values in Google Data Studio

Tags: sql, looker-studio

Is there a way to group the values under dimensions that are used in Data Studio? I think this can be resolved with some SQL skills.

What I want to do is further aggregate the data under a dimension that I am retrieving from CloudSQL.

So there are phone device bundling values under the dimension of "bundling_type":

- existing customer Postpaid SIM with phone
- New postpaid SIM with phone
- Move to us Postpaid SIM with phone (new sim, keep number)
- Move prepaid to postpaid SIM with phone
- Device only (no bundle)

What I want to do is aggregate all the SIM bundling values into just one, so I can map this out in a pie/donut chart (for the dimension "bundling_type":

- Device Only Vs
- Device with SIM bundle

What it the best and most simple approach to this  in Data Studio? I think I have to write some CASE SQL statements and generate a new custom dimension from the current one.

Edit: I have tried using a case statement which is down below:

```
CASE
WHEN REGEX_MATCH(tmvh_order_type, "(Device Only)") THEN "Device Only"
WHEN REGEX_MATCH(tmvh_order_type, "(Bundle|MNP)") THEN "Device Bundle"
ELSE "Review: New Category"
END
```

However, it returns syntax errors "Invalid formula - Invalid input expression. - Unsupported filter"

Answer (score 0):

I looked at Google Data Studio more closely and realised that the expression should be `REGEXP` and not `REGEX`

Also my expressions had to match the regex precisely as they are not 'regex contains' expressions. So this is what worked:

```
CASE
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(tmvh_order_type, "(Bundle - Exist change PP|Bundle - New|MNP - 2 Step|MNP - Share Plan)") THEN "Device Bundle"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(tmvh_order_type, "Device Only") THEN "Device Only"
ELSE "Other"
END
```